# Stop asp:SqlDataSource column from displaying '00:00:00' next to my date

Tags: asp.net

I have an `asp.net` web application and on one page I have an `asp:GridView` which is populated with the following code:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlAdminTasks" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PaydayLunchConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="GetAdminTasks" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Admin_TaskList] ([Description], [Checkbox_Radio_Value], [Action_For], [Location], [Additional_Info], [Date_Submitted], [Submitted_By], [Status]) VALUES (@Description, @Checkbox_Radio_Value, @Action_For, @Location, @Additional_Info, @Date_Submitted, @Submitted_By, @Status)">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Action_For" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Checkbox_Radio_Value" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Additional_Info" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Submitted" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Submitted_By" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I populate my `SQL` db, the date is displayed as '2016-01-04' so does not display a time, but when I hit the page my grid displays as '04-01-2016 00:00:00'.  I don't want the timestamp to be displayed but I cant figure out how to stop it as all the grid is all rendered in my `.aspx` file.

My `SQL` db is working fine, the issue is the code above.

The reason I do not want the timestamp is because the page has limited space so I want to keep column widths, small as possible and the timestamp has no relevance to the user anyway.

Comment: The issue is apparently not the code that inserts the data into the db but rather the lack of proper formatting in your grid where you display the data. Instead of the `SqlDataSource`, show how your grid looks like.

Comment: most likely you need to add DataFormatString {0:d} or 0:d to your gridview datetime column

Comment: @Creator Can you please suggest the {0:d} as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your grid view datetime column you need to set the DataFormatString to {0:d} 
This will format the datetime to only show the date